# Error al intentar correr el método takePicture de CameraX

Tags: android, android-studio

He estado intentando desarrollar una app que me permita tomar una foto y guardarla con CameraX.

```
CapImg.takePicture(img,null, new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onImageSaved(File file) {
                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),CapImg.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
                   @Override
                   public void onError(ImageCapture.ImageCaptureError imageCaptureError, String message, Throwable cause) {

                   }
               });
```

Al llegar a este método se cierra la app de manera forzada.

```
ImageCaptureConfig ImgCapConf = new ImageCaptureConfig.Builder().setTargetRotation(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()).build();
    ImageCapture CapImg = new ImageCapture(ImgCapConf);
```

Este es el ImageCapture configurado que utilizo.

---

Al revisar el LogCat se saca el siguiente error.

```
2020-02-03 23:54:54.911 27532-28395/com.example.projectmob E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: CameraX-camerax_io_0
Process: com.example.projectmob, PID: 27532
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void java.util.concurrent.Executor.execute(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference
    at androidx.camera.core.ImageSaver.postError(ImageSaver.java:133)
    at androidx.camera.core.ImageSaver.run(ImageSaver.java:116)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1187)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

Comment: Recuerda que es importante revisar el LogCat esto para encontrar el problema y solucionarlo ràpidamente, que mensaje de error se muestra?

Comment: Utilizo mi celular para testear la App así que no puedo tener un LogCat.

Comment: Usando tu celular tambien puedes ver lo que sucede en el LogCat, no instalas directamente de Android Studio tu aplicacion?

Comment: Me saco el error de abajo cuando lo instalo directamente por Android Studio.